# How to perform joins at particular ID using MongoDB and NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb

As i'm a new bee to MongoDB, having difficulty in performing joins in collections. I need to join the two collections at particular ID. Actually i'm using models for the database purpose.

Collection 1

```
{

   "id" : "1",

   "user_id" : "101",

   "job_id" : "j1001"

}

{

   "id" : "2",

   "user_id" : "101",

   "job_id" : "j1002"

}

{

   "id" : "3",

   "user_id" : "101",

   "job_id" : "j1003"

}
```

Collection 2

```
{

   "id" : "1",

   "job_id" : "j1001",

   "name" : "Software engineer",

}

{

   "id" : "2",

   "job_id" : "j1002",

   "name" : "Project manager"

}

{

   "id" : "3",

   "job_id" : "j1003",

   "name" : "FullStack Developer"

}
```

I want to retrieve all the names in collection2 where the user_id is `101` in collection1

The expected result would be like this

```
{"Software engineer", "Project manager", "FullStack Developer"}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Are there fields common to join on? Your question isn’t clear. Also if you have relational data you’ll be better off using a relational database.

Comment: As @abdulbarik said you have to use `Aggregate` , refer this for more idea https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1077839/Working-with-MongoDBs-lookup-Aggregator

Answer (score 0):

You can use [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) stage with [aggregate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) framework of MongoDB.

Syntax of the

```
{
   $lookup:
     {
       from: <collection to join>,
       localField: <field from the input documents>,
       foreignField: <field from the documents of the "from" collection>,
       as: <output array field>
     }
}
```

Example

```
db.collection1.aggregate([
   {
     $lookup:
       {
         from: "collection2",
         localField: "id1",
         foreignField: "reference id which will be same as id1",
         as: "Array_Docs"
       }
  }
])
```